# Linking outside from a flow

Tags: visualforce, workflow, flow

In my flow inside a screen element I want to build a dynamic link
that will be built from input inserted from the customer.
the beginning of the link is permanent but the end dynamic - for example:
https://www.google.co.il/?id=1234
assuming the "1234" is an input field from one of the previous steps 
and that the user can press that link in the flow.
How can i do it?
Thanks,
Udi

Comment: Did you create a variable to hold the "1234"?

Comment: Yes, assume variable exsits

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [Knowledge base from flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61281/knowledge-base-from-flow) which I believe should provide you with the essence of the answer to your question.

Assemble the URL from the value saved in your variable, then send it back to your controller as the finish location.