# Knowledge base from flow

Tags: visualforce, workflow, flow

I want to end my flow with an option to open a solution or knowledgbase page from within SF.
How can I do it?
Thanks,
Udi

Comment: Tried to find an action like "open solution" or something similar but there isn't one. I'm kind of new to the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways we can try and achieve this .The flow finish URL or action can be controlled .

```
￼<apex:page>
   <flow:interview name="MyUniqueFlow" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/home/home.jsp')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

The below example for navigating to a VF

```
￼<apex:page>
<flow:interview name="MyUniqueFlow" finishLocation="{!$Page.MyUniquePage}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Even you can use controller action also to control the behaviour

```
public class myFlowController {
   public PageReference getPageA() {
    return new PageReference('/300');
    }
    public String getPageB() {
        return '/300';
   }
   public String getPageC() {
       return '/apex/my_finish_page';
   }
 }
```

Configure in finish location as below

```
<apex:page controller="myFlowController">
<h1>Congratulations!</h1> This is your new page.
   <flow:interview name="flowname" finishLocation="{!pageA}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Also you can always pass parameters from flow

The above should get you started on how to crack the solution

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_vf.htm

Comment: Hi,Thanks! Its basically a decision tree implemented in SF flow with each leaf being a knowledge base page - let's say i have a decision - is the light on or off - if off i want to open a solution page "instructions for light off" but if its on i want to continue the flow

Comment: You can do that via last option .Since you can call the controller method you can write logic .Flow can be used inside VF and you can use get set methods .Please see the updated answer link.

Comment: Configure flow such that based on decision it either exists flow by setting a variable or continue the flow